# application/plain MIME type for text?

Tags: text, mime-types, mime

I have seen this application/plain mentioned with .text suffix in some [sources](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml). Is it valid and has it been used anywhere? Or is this just a case where someone compiled a list and others just copied it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a valid MIME type according to the IANA: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html

Sadly, that doesn't mean you won't encounter it in the real world. ;-)

Comment: We better choose text/html is this what you are saying ?